# Getting codemirror to highlight Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I am using the codemirror source editor but cannot get it to work for clojure. Has anyone managed to do this?

Comment: there is [lezer-parser/clojure](https://github.com/lezer-parser/clojure), where lezer is the default parser for codemirror, but there is not-yet a `codemirror/lang-clojure` to interface between parser and editor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not yet. If you're trying to implement a Clojure mode, feel free to ask specific questions in the google group ( http://groups.google.com/group/codemirror ).

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been a while since the question was asked; I'd like to fill in that CodeMirror2 now has Clojure mode.

http://codemirror.net/mode/clojure/index.html